# Spring-AMQP RPC container

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Exist a container on the spring-amqp that support a reply-to feature?

I want make RPCs like https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html, but using spring-amqp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply).

On the server side, the message listener container, when used with a message listener adapter will automatically handle the replies. You can also use the template's `...receiveAndReply` methods on the server side.

**EDIT**

Note that we now have [Spring Boot implementations of all 6 tutorials](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/rabbitmq-tutorials).

Comment: Thanks. It works by MessageListenerAdapter.handleMessage() with return, but using the template, the program caught only the first message and no more after. I ran the template with no container.

Comment: We use it all the time; turn on DEBUG logging and all should become clear.

Comment: Cloud you please give me any example link. I that document what is foo.serviceInterface. what are the methods we have

Comment: Any method you want - it's your interface; that form of RPC (remote method invocation) is not a modern pattern, though - it tightly couples the client and server. Also see my edit - we now have implementations of the tutorials.